# Does honey and cinnamon cure any diseases?

Tags: medical-science, natural-remedies, cancer, honey

While I know the answer is no, I was baffled to see this posted on a friends Facebook page and figured this would be the best place to find the facts, that and I suck at research. I feel fallacies like this need to be fought with facts.

The claim is that drug companies don't want you to know that simply making a mixture of honey and cinnamon can cure virtually anything including cancer, heart disease and arthritis, please help me dispel this!

[Quoting the terrible science](http://www.naturalnews.com/039963_cinnamon_honey_healing.html#ixzz2XKEK2JgX):

> Please allow me to preface this article with a bit of information unbeknown to the writer and virtually everyone else: cinnamon is 26 percent sulfur based and honey is 33 percent sulfur based, making their combination 59 percent sulfur based and the reason why their combination is so effective.

Comment: Mixing something that is 26% with something that is 33% gives you a mixture that is anywhere between 26% and 33% (29.5% on average), not 59%. Another question is what do these percentages refer to? Because that's most definitely not the sulfur content in neither cinnamon nor honey. In fact they don't contain sulfur at all.

Comment: @vartec: There is a reason I wrote "Quoting the terrible science:" :)

Comment: "Any disease" is rather broad and makes it very difficult to falsify. How about picking one of the claimed diseases from the list?

Comment: This is a hoax started in a supermarket tabloid around 1995 and resurfaces periodically. See http://www.snopes.com/medical/homecure/honey.asp Knowing that the source produces works of fiction is not a slam dunk argument against the claims, but it seems so unlikely to be true based on these origins that I just don't care if scientists ever formally debunk it.

Comment: As @Oddthinking said above, this is clearly too broad and poorly defined to be answered definitely.

Answer (score 4):

There are [several allegations and studies](https://www.google.com/search?q=diabetese+cinnamon) which suggest that cinnamon does or may help regulate insulin levels in diabetics.

However the [American Diabetes Society disagrees](http://www.diabetes.org/news-research/research/access-diabetes-research/baker-cinnamon-has-no-benefit-for-people-with-diabetes.html), saying,

> Cinnamon cannot replace medication, a healthy diet, and exercise for people with diabetes who are trying to prevent serious heart problems.

A balanced summary might be [this one](http://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/cinnamon-for-diabetes-the-consequences-of-natural-alternatives/) which says,

> But look closer. **The results may be statistically significant, but they’re not that impressive compared to medication.** Cinnamon lowered A1C by 0.09%, versus the usual 1% with medication. Give [sic] A1c reflects overall glucose trends, cinnamon doesn’t look that impressive. Even at the extreme of the confidence interval, cinnamon has, at best, 10% of the efficacy of drug treatments. At worst, it’s completely ineffective.

Comment: Note that those studies deal with [Cinnamomum verum](http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl/record/kew-2721692), not [Cinnamomum cassia](http://www.theplantlist.org/tpl/record/kew-2721201). In some locations, one is [more likely](http://www.fao.org/docrep/x5326e/x5326e07.htm) to find the latter type of cinnamon than the former type.

Comment: In any case, even if it were as effective as insulin it does not **cure** diabetes.